# template(flowers) matching on android

Tags: android, opencv

Right now I am working on an android and ios project, and this app will allow people to visit a place(like a park), and it will contain a feature that can let user to know what kind of flower by scanning the flower with their phone, and thw app will match the flower in the database.

Well, the problem I have is, there are ways I can do this template matching thing, and now I have two ways:

```
  1.use OpenCV for both android and iosSimple RGB analysis using java
  2.Simple RGB analysis using java
```

But both of these ways seems not so peefect. At first, I searched for template matching, and there seems to be a lot of people talking about OpenCV. But I realized that OpenCV is only supported up to android 4.0, so I tried to find a way that makes this more simple, which is using a simple JAVA code with RGB matching. But here's another problem: simple RGB matching is not a great idea for flowers, and even though every flowers has different colors, different cameras may cause the RGB result to be very different.

Is there any better way to match flowers? 
(Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: You probably don't realize it yet... But it's a very difficult research topic-like [problem](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/nq6yMBmfY3apuyHqe8gwbCzgVob7EvAY4LefDSyRw44BHiFhfMwQ49pkr8nim2HGO1FR_GQmxOWxMIJK2b9MgWNPururMOuk2O_wVWi3mfFEPcWmriGvCtQSF5uYluzv9POlbB8)

Comment: as @Miki said, that's a very challenging task, probably you won't get good results at all. Maybe have a look at Leafsnap (googled): http://neerajkumar.org/papers/nk_eccv2012_leafsnap.pdf how they solved the "template matching"

Comment: @Micka nice paper! Probably (as usual, recently) you can get good results with deep learning. Probably the one trained on [ImageNet](http://www.image-net.org/search?q=flower) will provide acceptable results

Comment: @Miki thanks for the website, I just want my project to be done, didn't know that this would be so complicate

Comment: @Micka just checked that pdf, I think I should try it with MATLAB? I will try to build it myself, but those math......

Comment: sorry, I didnt read the whole paper, so I can't help there ;) Using Matlab to build a prototype might be ok, but sometimes it isn't practicable because of processing time while testing the prototype :D

Comment: Probably the fastest way to get this done (but I can't guarantee) is: 1) download [caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/) 2) Use [default training on ImageNet](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/imagenet.html) 3) follow instructions and have fun :D. You can test if this actually would work uploading some of your images [here](http://demo.caffe.berkeleyvision.org/) and check if results are ok